# AJAX request randomly stop working and returns error 400

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a problem with my WP-blog and I have no any idea how I can solve it.
I have custom pagination, wrote on jQuery and AJAX and some times it works fine but sometimes I have an error `POST https://my-site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)`

Here is my code in `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_paginator');
function ajax_paginator()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-paginator', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-paginator.js');
}
```

and in ajax-paginator.js is usual jQuery code. So, what can be reason of this errors and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you edit your question? Because the code that you posted adds only an JavaScript file to your page. Can you show the actually code for the Ajax request?

Comment: Generally the problem was in Wordefence plugin, when I turn it off, AJAX begin works fine

Comment: Save my week... (here is a solution: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordfence-blocking-ajax-requests/)